# Angular 2 setinterval() keep running on other component

Tags: angular

I have the following method in one component:

```
ngOnInit()
        {
            this.battleInit();
            setInterval(() => {
                this.battleInit(); 
                }, 5000);
        }
```

Now, I need to run this interval only if the user is in this specific component, that means that when the user navigate away from this component the interval will stop.

Currently, `this.battleInit()` is executed every 5 seconds, even after the user navigates away from this page.

Short question: How do I stop `setInterval()` when user navigate away (by routing) to another component?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

You need to use `clearInterval` method for this within the `ngOnDestroy` hook method of your component. For this you need to save the returned value by the `setInterval` method.

Here is a sample:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.battleInit();
  this.id = setInterval(() => {
    this.battleInit(); 
  }, 5000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.id) {
    clearInterval(this.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What will `console.log(this.id)` return?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier: Can you pls solve my issue , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836512/angular2-6-setinterval-is-not-cancelling-stopping-even-though-we-called-clearint

Comment: If someone is using Ionic you can also change _ngOnInit_ for _ionViewDidLoad_ and _ngOnDestroy_ for _ionViewDidLeave_.

Comment: Great answer! Helped me, but a small update would to this would help. Include the declaration of this.id and its type. The type is NodeJS.Timeout. So this code: id = new NodeJS.Timeout()

Answer (score 7):

every 40 seconds

```
 polling: any;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.consulta();
    this.pollData();
  }

 pollData () {
    this.polling = setInterval(() => {
    this.consulta();

  },40*1000)

 ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.polling);
  }
```