# clearInterval() not working in Angular 5 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, clearinterval

setInterval() working fine for me and timer starts, but clearInterval() doesn't stop timer when counter value reached to 100. It running continuously. Any help appreciated.

Below is my component code -

```
export class AppComponent {
  counter=0;
  progressInterval;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.progressInterval=setInterval(()=>{
      this.counter=this.counter+10;
      if(this.counter>=100){        
          clearInterval(this.progressInterval);
      }
    },200);
  }
}
```

Below is my component HTML code -

```
<p style="margin:20px;">
    <ngb-progressbar
      type="warning"
      [value]="counter"
      [striped]="true"
      [animated]="true"
    >{{counter}}</ngb-progressbar>
  </p>
```

and here is screenshot which shows progressbar -

[Screenshot](http://www.screencast.com/t/r7Wwk65Ra)

Thanks

Comment: Your code is 100% fine , and it also clearing timeout there is no issue.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: Are you modifying `this.progressInterval` or `this.counter` somewhere else in your class?

Comment: @JoseAPL no, I am not. Thanks

Comment: @Rahul is that the whole code of the AppComponent class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Issue got fix for me. I forgot to import "clearInterval" from "timers" module. Now i updated like below and it worked now.

```
import { 
  setInterval,
  clearInterval
} from 'timers';
```

Thanks for all for helping me on this.

Thanks

Comment: That is weird. Are you using Angular CLI? It should not be needed to import timers at all.

Comment: @Emocuc Yes, it also looks weird to me. Yes, I am using Angular CLI. Even I am confused why i had to import timers module.

Comment: Try updating your package to latest. Just recently we got Angular 5.2.2 and Angular CLI 1.6.6. ... other dependencies grown as well, compared to default Angular CLI seed

Answer (score 4):

Or you can assign the interval to a variable. Lets say like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    const int = setInterval( () => {
      this.counter += 10;
      if ( this.counter >= 100 ){        
          clearInterval( int );
      }
    }, 200);
  }
```

Comment: Which differs from what he has done in what way, exactly?

Comment: I have placed it as an option, saying 'or you can' -> I think in many cases it is not great idea to populate the component's space with more references -> he is using the interval as part of this. scope, but likely he is not accessing it after initial lifecycle ended, hence it is just overpopulating the space, the const would keep it only in that initial lifecycle scope ... also I think the syntax is more comprehensive ...

Comment: @tiagodws the scope! it's not useful to assign attributes to a class if you won't use in other parts of your class. `this. progressInterval` is class scope which is only used in this method so having a local scope for the interval will be better

Comment: I am setting to this counter value to ng-bootstrap progress bar. but progressbar not getting stop even after reaching to 100. Any help?

Comment: @Rahul - pls, update your question and show how exactly the code looks like. thnx

Comment: @Rahul - what is config.max value in your progressbar-config.ts ?

Comment: @Emocuc Where is this file? I am not aware with it. Plz let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Rahul - if you do not know where it is, then you have not changed it it should be set to 100 by default ... so to clarify, you can see in your progressbar counter incrementing from 0 - 100, but as far it reaches 100, the progressbar does not disappear, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Tested with ES6 modules (**try this with chrome 61 onwards**)

```html
<script type="module">
  class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
      this.counter = 0;
      this.progressInterval;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.progressInterval = setInterval(() => {
        this.counter += 10;
        console.log('this.counter', this.counter);

        if(this.counter >= 100){
          clearInterval(this.progressInterval);
          console.log('cleaned and finished');
        }
      },200);
    }
  }

  const instance = new AppComponent();
  
  instance.ngOnInit();
</script>
```

Your code with ES6 syntax works perfectly.
Seems there is another behavior with Angular5 check this answer:

[Angular 2 setinterval() keep running on other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116619/angular-2-setinterval-keep-running-on-other-component?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

It's due to this variable scope is limited for that current function only.
and interval function have it's own this variable so it can't detect this.progressInterval variable.

Try using this way:

```
ngOnInit(){

    const initScope = this;
    this.progressInterval=setInterval(()=>{
      initScope.counter=initScope.counter+10;
      if(initScope.counter>=100){        
          clearInterval(initScope.progressInterval);
      }
    },200);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things to consider in any implementation of Interval in Angular:

1. Make sure you're only instantiating it once.  In this example, if you were to leave the component and return before the counter was cleared, it would create a second instance while the original kept going.
2. Have a fail-safe clearing of the interval when leaving the page or component scope using OnDestroy.  You always need to clear/dispose the interval when done.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

[..]

export class YourComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  progressInterval: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    [..]
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.progressInterval) { clearInterval(this.progressInterval); }
  }

}
```