# JavaScript: setTimeOut inside another setTimeOut (nested setTimeOut) to stimulate the API response not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, mocking, settimeout

**Requirement**: User continuously scans the job numbers in a textbox without any delay. For each jobnumber I need to call an API in background to get the details of scanned job numbers.

**What I have done:** 
I written a small mock up code to stimulate this requiremnt. 
I am delaying the user scanning and delaying the API response as well with setTimeOuts

**Issue:** 
Delaying the Scanning is working fine but delaying the API response is not working.

**jsbin link**
[code in jsbin](https://jsbin.com/pegofax/edit?js,console)

Please run the below code and check the console.

```js
var dataset = [10, 20, 30];
var delay = 100;
var apiDelay = 3000;



function execute(dataset) {    
    var i = 0;
    scannedJob(dataset, i);
}


//1ST TIME OUT METHOD//
function scannedJob(dataset, i) {

    setTimeout(function() {
              console.log("Scanned Job Number ="+dataset[i]+" @  time = " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());


        fireJobSearchHttpAPI1(dataset[i]);

        i++;

        if (dataset.length > i) {
            self.scannedJob(dataset, i);
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, delay);
}

//2nd TIME OUT METHOD//

/* TWO TYPES OF METHODS I WRITTEN , BOTH ARE NOT WORKING,
EXPECTED:  Each API call should fire with 5sec delay. Instead all 3 api calls given response after 5 seconds. I need each call should take 5sec and total at the end it should take 15 seconds., 
BUT FIRING ALL THE JOB NUMBERS IMMEDIATELY WITHOUT DELAY
*/
function fireJobSearchHttpAPI1(jobNum) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("job number '"+jobNum+"' API FIRED @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        }, apiDelay);

}


function fireJobSearchHttpAPI2(jobNum) {
    (function myLoop(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("job number '"+jobNum+"' API FIRED  @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
           if (--i) myLoop(i);
        }, apiDelay)
    })(1);

}


//Main Method
execute(dataset);
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected, I mean the way your code is the way that code is executing, so What exactly you need ? becase the delayingAPI is executing as expected, it waits for 3 seconds to execute, each one of them.

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez: Each API call should fire with 5sec delay. Instead all 3 api calls given response after 5 seconds. I need each call should take 5sec and total at the end it should take 15 seconds.

Comment: so the way that your doing your code is immediately executing, you need to mutiply each index to the api delay value

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass as a argument the current `index`, so then you need to multiply that index for your current api call delay, so when is the first step it will be (index = 0), so you should do it something like `(index + 1) * apiDelay` then it would be 5000, sencond step, index would be 1 then `(index + 1) * apiDelay` would be 10000, and the last step `index` would be 2, then `(index + 1) * apiDelay` would be 15000.

At the bottom some modification was done to your current code.

```js
var dataset = [10, 20, 30];
var delay = 100;
var apiDelay = 5000;



function execute(dataset) {    
    var i = 0;
    scannedJob(dataset, i);
}


//1ST TIME OUT METHOD//
function scannedJob(dataset, i) {

    setTimeout(function() {
              console.log("Scanned Job Number ="+dataset[i]+" @  time = " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());


        fireJobSearchHttpAPI1(dataset[i], i);

        i++;

        if (dataset.length > i) {
            self.scannedJob(dataset, i);
        } else {
            i = 0;
        }
    }, delay);
}

//2nd TIME OUT METHOD//

/* TWO TYPES OF METHODS I WRITTEN , BOTH ARE NOT WORKING,
EXPECTED:  Each API call should fire with 5sec delay. Instead all 3 api calls given response after 5 seconds. I need each call should take 5sec and total at the end it should take 15 seconds., 
BUT FIRING ALL THE JOB NUMBERS IMMEDIATELY WITHOUT DELAY
*/
function fireJobSearchHttpAPI1(jobNum, index) {
        console.log("index", ((index + 1) * apiDelay))
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("job number '"+jobNum+"' API FIRED @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
        }, ((index + 1) * apiDelay));

}


function fireJobSearchHttpAPI2(jobNum) {
    (function myLoop(i) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("job number '"+jobNum+"' API FIRED  @ " + new Date().toLocaleTimeString());
           if (--i) myLoop(i);
        }, apiDelay)
    })(1);

}


//Main Method
execute(dataset);
```

Comment: its working , thanks. I have an issue which I am continuously suffering from past 4 days. Can you check the issue once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836512/angular2-6-setinterval-is-not-cancelling-stopping-even-though-we-called-clearint