# Is this the correct way to build a Countdown Timer in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a countdown timer function in Angular that will keep executing every second. To call the function, I am using `setInterval`. This will be used in a mobile app (Ionic).

```js
setInterval(() => {
  this.countdownTime = this.getCountDownTime(date1,date2);
  console.log(this.countdownTime);
}, 1000);
```

Is this the correct way to update the time every second? Or, is there an efficient alternative?

Comment: In my opinion your solution is correct. Your binding needs to be done to the countdownTime property and then everything is working correctly. Are there any problems in efficiency?

Comment: As functionality it will give you what you want , but for performance reasons its bad since it causes the app to have much performance and thus will cause device over heating. If you could try to use a for loop statement that breaks after some time when reaches a specific value then restarts and keep on till you reach your desired purpose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a timer in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50455347/how-to-do-a-timer-in-angular-5)

Comment: @MostafaHarb, I do not agree. A simple setInterval that runs every second is not that CPU intensive, not will it cause overheats. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650134/is-setinterval-cpu-intensive) for more information.

Comment: He didn't say he want to stop the interval, he wants it to keep working all the time, and if it keeps so it will cause performance problems...

Comment: Consider using rxjs interval / timer. I guess the "purest" angular way would be to build it with observables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. Just make sure to clear the interval using `clearInterval` when you want it to stop:

```js
const delay = 1000;
let interval;

function start() {
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    this.countdownTime = this.getCountDownTime(date1,date2);
    console.log(this.countdownTime);
  }, delay);
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

Comment: But if I navigate to another component, will it be required to use clearInterval?

Comment: It depends, but that's probably the best solution. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116619/angular-2-setinterval-keep-running-on-other-component) to find out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The best way of handling countdowns in Angular is using the CountdownPipe. CountdownPipe efficiently updates the UI without blocking the main thread, ensuring a responsive user interface. setInterval can block the UI thread and lead to flickering in the user interface. Using setInterval may lead to unpredictable UI issues, impacting API requests and modals.

#### count-down.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, timer, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Pipe({
  name: 'countdown'
})
export class CountdownPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private getMsDiff = (futureDate: string): number => (+(new Date(futureDate)) - Date.now());

  private msToTime(msRemaining: number): string {
    const days: string | number = Math.floor(Math.abs(msRemaining) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    let hours: string | number = Math.floor((Math.abs(msRemaining) % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes: string | number = Math.floor((Math.abs(msRemaining) % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds: string | number = Math.floor((Math.abs(msRemaining) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    hours = (hours < 10) ? '0' + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    if (msRemaining < 0) {
      return `-${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    } else {
      return `${days}:${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
  }

  public transform(futureDate: string, isPaused: boolean = false): Observable<string> | null {
    if (!futureDate) {
      return null;
    }
    let msRemaining = this.getMsDiff(futureDate);
    const countdownSubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(this.msToTime(msRemaining));

    if(!isPaused){
      timer(0, 1000)
        .pipe(
          map(() => {
            msRemaining -= 1000;
            const countdown =  this.msToTime(msRemaining);
            countdownSubject.next(countdown);
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    }


    return countdownSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

#### app.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Countdown-Timer-Pipe';
  dueDate = '2023-11-30T00:00:00' // Also, Works with YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.msz date format.
  pauseTimerSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  isPaused = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pauseTimerSubject.subscribe(v => {
      this.isPaused = v;
    })
  }
  pauseTime() {
    this.pauseTimerSubject.next(true);
  }

}
```

#### app.component.html

```
<p><span><span>Non Pausable Count Down Timer </span>{{ dueDate | countdown | async }}</span></p>
<p><span><span>Pausable Count Down Timer </span>{{ dueDate | countdown : isPaused | async}}</span></p>
<button *ngIf="!isPaused" (click)="pauseTime()">Pause Timer </button>
```