# setTimeout continues when user route to different page, how to clearTimeout in angular typscript?

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout, cleartimeout

I used setTimeout to jump to the upload page after 10 seconds. But the timeout continues when user navigate to another page. I followed the instructions on this link([Angular 2 setinterval() keep running on other component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116619/angular-2-setinterval-keep-running-on-other-component)) and added clearTimeout to ngOnDestroy, but it does not work.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    
    // Get uploaded file info
    this.uploadService.getFileInfo().subscribe((value) => {
      this.fileInfo = value;
    

      this.http.post(environment.apiUrl+'/api/dataValidation/validateData.php', this.fileInfo)
        .subscribe(res => {
          console.log('response'+res)
          if (res['length']<5) {
            
            //console.log(res);
            this.failure = true;
            this.fileValidationResults.errorMessage =res[0];
            this.loading = false; // stop loading screen
            this._timer =setTimeout(() => {
              this.router.navigate(["/uploads/upload"]);
            }, 10000); 
          }
        })
    });

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this._timer){
      clearTimeout(this._timer);
  };
  }
```

How can I stop setTimeout() when user navigate to another link and let setTimeout() only works in it's own component?

Comment: I figured out why, two timer instances were generated in ngOnInit() and ngOnDestroy() only clears the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Should** work, remember when declare your component implements OnDestroy

BTW, You can use `timer` operator of rxjs instead of setTimeout

```
import {timer} from 'rxjs'
import {takeWhile} from 'rxjs/operators'
...

export class OneComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {

   alive:boolean=true;

   ngOnInit(){    
     timer(1000).pipe(takeWhile(()=>this.alive)).subscribe(_=>{
        this.router.navigate(['/three'])
     })
   }

   ngOnDestroy()
   {
       this.alive=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! OnDestroy was implemented. The setTimeout does not work but timer indeed works. Interesting.